# This page has a redirect loop when using HTTP Redirect in IIS 8

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, http, redirect

This one's got me...all I'm trying to do is use the HTTP Redirect feature in IIS 8 to redirect to a different page/directory, but when I do, it says this page has a redirect loop.

The site has bindings as such:

```
http  <blank>      80  *
https de.com.edu  443  *
```

In HTTP Redirect I'm trying to redirect to

```
https://de.com.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin
```

And I'm checking the box that says "redirect all requests to exact destination". Then as I said I just get a "this page has a redirect loop". Any advice?

Comment: It looks like you're not giving us enough information. How exactly is the redirect rule written? Could you confirm you have a line similar to [http redirect](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) in the iis documentation?

Comment: I'm not writing a redirect rule I'm literally just using the "HTTP Redirect" feature in the IIS control panel which doesn't have many options besides "redirect requests to this page".

Comment: That kind of explains your problem. You're redirecting all traffic from https://de.com.edu to https://de.com.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin ... Which includes redirecting it after the redirect, which causes a loop. You'll need to write actual redirect rules in the config files for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Creating a redirect rule doesn't seem to do anything either...http://gyazo.com/afc48c8d7d3fae82024eddc39e297ec1